# remove permalink "front part" for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

Let's suppose I have CPT "event". In register_post_type, I've set

```
'slug' => 'event'
```

Then, in Wordpress settings I've set following Permalink structure

```
Custom: http://www.domain.tld/news/%postname%/
```

The problem is, URL for my "Event" CPT is

```
www.domain.tld/news/event/<event-name>
```

and I want

```
www.domain.tld/event/<event-name>
```

how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the argument:

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'event',
    'with_front' => false,
)
```

The 'with_front' flag controls whether to use the front part you've defined.